# Convert Early Bind Outlook to Late Bind Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, office-interop, com-interop

Ich have a specific code for Outlook that I would like to convert into late binding. However I am comparing some types, so I don't know how to make that comparison without having the dll loaded already.

```
var ol = (dynamic)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
dynamic windowType = ol.Application.ActiveWindow();
if (windowType is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorer) {
    Console.WriteLine("success")
}
```

I am not able to compile the code if I have not loaded the interop dll for Outlook. So I will have to add

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
```

Which I do not want to use because I won't know exactly what outlook version will be installed on the machine.
This is also the reason why I would want to use late Binding.

I tried to get the type with

```
Console.WriteLine($"This is my type {windowType.GetType()}");
```

But I would only get the result

```
This is my type System.__ComObject
```

Any Ideas how I can late bind outlook and still make type comparisons? Can specific types be loaded for comparison?

Comment: You could declare a COM interface manually and do a cast on it to really make sure, but why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the interop dll of the oldest version of Outlook you are planning to support (e.g., Outlook 2013). If you need to access functionality only available in the newer versions, use late binding. There is no reason to access *all* Outlook objects using late binding only.

Comment: Interesting approach. This would mean  I would still ship the last dll. But how would I load a function with late binding then? Lets say I would like to check if the mail that is beeing typed is an inline reponse?

Comment: Cast it to the `MailItem` interface using `is` or `as` operator, or read the `Class` property using late binding (all Outlook Objects expose it). It will be 43 (`OlObjectClass.olMail`) for the `MailItem` objects

Comment: One Problem persist. I actually do not want to ship a dll because I will not know weather it will be windows x64 or arm. I would like my program not to depend on a built dll. This is why I would only use late binding if possible. But as far as I can see there is no correct way to identify where the dll is and load it correctly with late binding.

Comment: interop dll is "Any CPU" - it does not contain any code, and it is really just a binary header file.